# Goldstone boson couple to conserved current

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

The [Goldstone boson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson) in spontaneous symmetry breaking problem couples naturally to the associated conserved current of the broken symmetry. How can I see a rigorous (mathematical) derivation for that?

Comment: You can search for a proof of the Quantum Nambu-Goldstone theorem. Try Hanzel & Martin - Quarks & Leptons.

Comment: No, that's not it, but thank you. I figure out the answer: it's just the very definition of the Goldstone (base on the parameter of the generated symmetry which is broken), and the associated conserved current.

Answer (score 2):

From Goldstone theorem we know that $\langle0|J^\mu|\pi\rangle$ isn't zero, that's all.

Adding some extra details, from Lorentz symmetry you have $\langle0|J^\mu|\pi\rangle\sim p^\mu e^{ip x}$ which you can get for a pion coupled derivatively to the current $\mathcal{L}\sim J^\mu \partial_\mu \pi$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little? This answer is so short that I feel it will be a hard for a general user to interpret its contents

Comment: I have just added a few extra infos.

Comment: I think you should clarify your notation somewhat and elaborate... It is still to short to be comprehensible for a general user.

Comment: What more do you want? The very heart of the WP article  linked takes you to the order parameter, the  nonvanishing vacuum expectations of transformation increments, 〈δφ<sub>g</sub>〉, specifying the relevant (Goldstone) null eigenvectors of the mass matrix! But this is just the integrated version of the above.

Comment: So, then, in the above notation of @TwoBs and the WP article, where the U(1) Goldstone boson φ<sub>g</sub> is denoted as π and the Goldstone sombrero potential v.e.v as f, note 0 ≠ Q|0〉= − ∫dx f² ∂₀ π  |0〉, just as in the Fabri-Picasso precursor theorem in that article.